# Does tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits account for batch size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

Does `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` account for batch size?

In my LSTM network, I feed batches of different sizes, and I would like to know whether or not I should normalize error with respect to batch size before optimizing.

Comment: I don't thing the batch size has anything to do with it. the lose is per example (however you define example). you can reduce mean afterwards to get the average loss for the batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) it says that the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits returns a vector with length equal to the batch size. To get a scalar cost you can do `tf.reduce_mean` on that vector. Then your loss will not be affected by the batch size.

Comment: Please, update the link to the documentation, which is now broken (404).